# linear Interpolation between points of dataframe using nearest points of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation

I need a quick solution to interpolate between the nearest points of a data frame without adding new points to a data frame if there is a lot of data - millions of points (without NANs). The dataframe is sorted using x vlaues.

E.g. I have a dataframe with the next columns:

```
x | y
-----
0 | 1
1 | 2
2 | 3
...
```

I need a function that will fire out for a given x_input value calculated as a linear interpolated value between nearest points, something like this:

`calc_linear(df, cinput_col = 'x', input_val=1.5, output_col=y)` will output 2.5 - as interpolated y value for a given x

Maybe there are some pandas functions for that?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`numpy.interp`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html):

```
import numpy as np

def calc_linear(df, input_val, input_col='x', output_col='y'):
    return np.interp(input_val, df[input_col], df[output_col])

y = calc_linear(df, 1.5)
print(y)

# Output
2.5
```